# Execute multiple python files in command line

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python code that uses a different python file. I can use the import statement to import the second file into the first, but my current situation is that I do not know what the second file is going to be. The expectation is that the file will be provided in a Makefile. In C/C++ we can recompile with -i/-l options. I am not sure how to accomplish something similar in python.

Here is a sample code:
**What works:**
myclass.py

```
class myclass:

def __init__(self):

    self.x = 10

def add(self, num):

    self.x += num

def get(self):

    return self.x
```

usemyclass.py

```
import sys

import myclass

c = myclass.myclass()

c.add(10)

print (c.get())
```

I can now run the code by invoking the python interpreter on usemyclass.py

python usemyclass.py

What I want is:

`usemyclass.py` (Do not import myclass.py, but pass it when invoking python)

```
import sys

c = myclass.myclass()


c.add(10)

print (c.get())
```

Now run with

`python myclass.py usemyclass.py` (or something like this)

I want to let users have the option of passing any python file (with restrictions on what class structure they have to implement). For example, a second user might write a myclass2.py as below

myclass2.py

```
class myclass: # They specify the same class name   
    def __init__(self):

        self.x = 1000

    def add(self, num):

        self.x = (self.x + num)%2000

    def get(self):

        return self.x
```

Comment: Your code isn't formatted correctly. Please try to fix that, it's very hard to read your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called **dynamic import**. The minimal working code is:

```
to_import = 'my_class_1.py'
exec('import {} as myclass'.format(to_import.split('.')[0]))
...
```

Of course you have to parse filenames from command line (for example, with `argparse`) and handle them properly. Also you may add exception handling since filenames are enterded by user, mimic imorting more closely and make it in a more secure fashion (or at least be aware of potential insecurity using `exec`).